# SQL DateDiff(mi) Calculation from different Columns and Rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 I'm trying to calculate the minutes between the `Time_End` and the next rows `Time_Start`. I've created a column called `RN` with sequential numbers based on `Time_Start` (which is actually a `datetime` column) using

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SearchDate Order By Time_Start) as RN
```

My data looks like this -

```
SearchDate  Time_Start  Time_End    RN
-----------------------------------------    
7/1/2015    1:52:33 AM  2:20:41 AM  1
7/1/2015    2:20:50 AM  2:58:00 AM  2
7/1/2015    2:58:06 AM  3:28:49 AM  3
7/1/2015    4:48:44 AM  5:23:53 AM  4
7/1/2015    5:45:22 AM  6:14:52 AM  5
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Sample of latest result -

```
SearchDate  Time_Start  Time_End    rn  diff_in_minutes
7/25/2014   3:27:02 PM  4:03:25 PM  8   11
7/25/2014   4:14:18 PM  4:48:37 PM  9   107
7/25/2014   6:35:29 PM  7:12:32 PM  10  9
7/25/2014   7:21:08 PM  7:57:23 PM  11  NULL
7/27/2014   9:26:00 PM  10:03:18 PM 1   26
7/27/2014   10:29:14 PM 11:06:52 PM 2   36
7/27/2014   11:42:38 PM 12:22:47 AM 3   NULL
7/28/2014   2:13:41 AM  2:51:25 AM  1   34
7/28/2014   3:25:28 AM  4:02:28 AM  2   5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to wrap your numbering query in a common table expression and then use that as the source and use a self-join on the row number - 1:

```
with cte as (
    select 
       SearchDate, 
       Time_Start, 
       Time_End, 
       row_number() over(partition by searchdate order by time_start) as rn 
    from t
) 

select 
    c1.searchdate, 
    datediff(mi, c1.time_end, c2.time_start) as diff_in_minutes
from 
    cte c1 
left join 
    cte c2 on c1.rn = c2.rn -1
```

The join should possibly include the date too so that you don't mix data from different days.

In later versions of SQL Server you could have used the`lead` function to access the subsequent row, which would have been easier.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! This works almost perfect after a little tweaking to fit the actual full dataset. The only issue I have now is if the Time_Start is before the previous rows Time_End the result is a null instead of a negative value as expected.

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure I understand; I tried inserting some rows with Time_Start is before the previous rows Time_End and got negative values. Could you update your sample data in the question with an example that gives this result?

Comment: Sorry I mis-spoke, the negative values are being shown as expected, the issue is confusing... It looks like the data is offset by one row , rn 1 diff_in_minutes should be null or 0 because there isn't a rn 0 but it's actually rn 1 time_end - rn 2 time_start. Then theres a problem going across days -

Comment: @Mike What would you like to happen when the date changes? Should the difference be calculated from the last time_end from the previous day?

Comment: @Mike If you could update the question and add an adjusted version of the output changed to the output you want it would be very helpful. I'm sure this is easy to fix once I understand what you want :)

Comment: Should the difference be calculated from the last time_end from the previous day? Yes, if there are multiple days.

Comment: The latest sample above shows the issue between days and the offset. Take rn 9 - the diff_in_minutes should be rn 9 time_start - rn 8 time_end but it's actually rn 10 - rn 9.

Comment: @Mike In your example should the end time `2014-07-25 19:57:23.000` be compared to the start time `2014-07-27 21:26:00.000` for a difference in minutes of `2969`?

Comment: @Mike Take a look at this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce241/2 Maybe that is what you want?

Comment: I think you stated it backwards but yes if that's what the data presents. Start time of 2014-07-27 21:26:00.000 minus the previous end time 2014-07-25 19:57:23.000

Comment: Perfect, thank you. This is it exactly, I just need to figure out why my data isn't resulting the same. There must be something else in my script.